# бот дискорда не находит команду

Tags: discord, discord.py

Я написал простенький код. Вроде всё работает однако когда ввожу комманду !slap мне пишет что команда не найдена[![вот1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xghb9.png)

вот код

```
import random

class Slapper(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        to_slap = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
        return f'{ctx.author} slapped {to_slap} because *{argument}*'

@bot.command()
async def slap(ctx, *, reason: Slapper):
    await ctx.send(reason)
```